# Why can't a BoxLayout be shared whereas a FlowLayout can?

Tags: java, swing, exception, flowlayout, boxlayout

I am confused by the following.

Case A

1. Set the layout manager for a JFrame as a BoxLayout.
2. Add a JButton to the JFrame container.
3. Compile.
4. Run.
5. Exception thrown:
   "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.AWTError: BoxLayout can't be shared"

Case B

1. Set the layout manager for a JFrame as a FlowLayout.
2. Add a JButton to the JFrame container.
3. Compile
4. Run
5. No exception thrown.

Why does Case A throw the exception and Case B does not? Why do FlowLayout and BoxLayout behave differently in this regard? What does it mean in Case A by the "BoxLayout can't be shared"?

I have read a few similar threads on this website about this exception message but I'm still confused about the comparison to FlowLayout and what the exception message means exactly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Simple answer

Basically, `"BoxLayout can't be shared"` in this situation means that you're trying to make your `JFrame` and its `contentPane()` share the same `BoxLayout` object.

---

### Advanced Explanation

When setting the `Layout` for a `JFrame`, it implicitely calls `getContentPane().setLayout(manager)` so you are actually setting the layout for the contentPane() and not for the frame itself.

This brings us to how the containers are checked within `BoxLayout` and `FlowLayout`.

---

**`FlowLayout`**

This layout does not have a constructor that will take the container as a parameter and thus will not, at the making of the object, consider the container. Neither has this class a `container` instance variable.

**`BoxLayout`**

`BoxLayout` on the contrary has a constructor that takes the container as a parameter and stocks it within the instance variable `target`. This is done to check it later within the `layoutContainer(container)` method. It has a `checkContainer(container)` method that will verify if the instance variable is equals to the container given in parameter. It throws `throw new AWTError("BoxLayout can't be shared");` if it is not the case.

---

This was an introduction to the following explaination.

As said within the first paragraph, `JFrame.setLayout(LayoutManager)` will call `JFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(LayoutManager)` and thus the `Layout` is set on the `contentPane()` which is a `JPanel` by default.

Check out the constructor of `BoxLayout(container, int)` and ask yourself :

Now I know that the Layout is set on the `JPanel` (`contentPane()`) and not the `JFrame` itself, which parameter will I give to this constructor?

Is it a good idea to give it the `JFrame` itself? Knowing that it is not the Component which on the Layout has been set?

**The answer is : of course it is not a good idea.**

Here is the correct way to achieve this :

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), ...);
```

**Why?**

Because we know now that the container is the **`contentPane()`** and that eventually, when adding a component for example, a check is going to happen and the parameter within the constructor must be the exact same `object` as the component where on the `layout` is set which does not happens with `FlowLayout` for example.

---

### **Sources**

[`BoxLayout`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/BoxLayout.java#BoxLayout)

- [`BoxLayout(Container, int)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/BoxLayout.java#BoxLayout.%3Cinit%3E%28java.awt.Container%2Cint%29)
- [`BoxLayout.checkContainer(Container)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/BoxLayout.java#BoxLayout.checkContainer%28java.awt.Container%29)
- [`BoxLayout.layoutContainer(Container)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/BoxLayout.java#BoxLayout.layoutContainer%28java.awt.Container%29)

[`FlowLayout`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/awt/FlowLayout.java#FlowLayout)

- [`FlowLayout.layoutContainer(Container)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/awt/FlowLayout.java#FlowLayout.layoutContainer%28java.awt.Container%29)

Comment: Thanks Yassin Hajaj for your answer.